# eclipse can not determine apache tomcat 7 on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm using eclipse 3.8 and running it on ubuntu 12.10 which has apache tomcat 7.
the problem is when I want to select tomcat as my server on eclipse runtime environment there is no option for selecting apache tomcat 7.

I've tested tomcat server at `localhost:8080` and it works.it seems there is no problem with tomcat itself but I don't know why I cant add it to eclipse.Is there any idea to solve this problem?

edit:
my eclise is not a java ee edition and I've installed java ee as a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I did it, it keeps the system tomcat and your own personal tomcat instance separate, and you don't have to change permissions or stop the tomcat running as a service.

Install tomcat as per normal: `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`

Install private instance support: `sudo apt-get install tomcat7-user`

Create local instance in your home folder:

```
tomcat7-instance-create -p 10080 -c 10005 mytomcat
```

Note: -p sets the port number (default is 8080) and -c is the control port (default 8005), we set these so we don't compete with the main installation of tomcat running as a service. "mytomcat" can be anything you like, but it will create a directory by this name in your home.

Now use the following to make Eclipse happy:

```
cd mytomcat
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/lib
ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar bin/bootstrap.jar
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar bin/tomcat-juli.jar
mkdir -p common/classes;
mkdir -p server/classes;
mkdir -p shared/classes;
```

Now within Eclipse you can create a Tomcat v7.0 server and set the installation directory as ~/mytomcat.

Note: common, server and shared classes could be links too, but I wanted to keep the two separate.

Answer (score 1):

please be more precise in your question: did you install Tomcat and Eclipse via APT? Is your Eclipse Java EE edition, or did you install the Java EE plugin?

I will suppose you got both from Ubuntu repository and you are using Eclipse for Java EE developers.

You look to http://lackovic.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/set-up-eclipse-and-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-create-java-restful-web-services-with-jersey/ and follow the how-to till step 13. For me worked flawlessly.

Before starting, you must stop the running service with `sudo service tomcat7 stop`. In fact, Eclipse needs to start his own instance of Tomcat, that is gonna crash if there is another Tomcat listening on 8080.

Please note that Ubuntu's Tomcat installation is a little bit different from the vanilla one: in fact, Ubuntu's maintainers decide to split up the base directory and the configuration directory, while Eclipse is going to look in the base directory for configurations.